# ", match" syntax Javascript

Tags: javascript

While reading through an implementation of a lightweight router I ran into a syntax form I haven't yet learned or seen yet.

```
   var re = /{{.+}}/g, match;
```

I understand the regular expression, but can't seem to find any documentation on the comma then "match" syntax. I've attempted to use this syntax like so:

```
   var test = "hello", match;
```

which also seems to work. Match is not that is declared within the code. Could anyone clarify or link to any documentation on the use of the comma operator in a variable assignment? I found this link on the comma operator: [MDN on Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). But I'm still struggling to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Is `match` defined before `re`?

Comment: Isn’t this just the same as `var re = /{{.+}}/g; var match;`?

Comment: @guest271314 -- match is not defined before re

Comment: Is `match` used after `re` assignment?

Comment: @Xufox oh holy cow. you might be right. damn i guess i was associating it with the regex match and was just thrown off by the unconventional RegEx double slash syntax.

Comment: I was also confused the first minute. But I for me the regex syntax isn’t unusual. I’d write it like this.

Comment: Yeah, the slashes are just standard JS regex literal syntax, they're not unconventional unless compared to other languages that only let you create a regex via a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is declaring 2 variables, one is called `re` the other is called `match` and has a value of `undefined`

Comment: will accept this as the answer when time limit is lifted.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), the variable assignment syntax is:

> var varname1 [= value1 [, varname2 [, varname3 ... [, varnameN]]]];

Hence you are declaring two variables here.